# Read documents with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a information retrieval assignment where I have to use elasticSearch to generate some indexing/ranking. I was able to download elasticSearch and it's now running on `http://localhost:9200/` but how do I read every documents stored in my folder called '`data`'?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rest-apis.html

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is just a search engine. In order to get your docs and files searchable, you need to load them, extract all relevant data and load into elasticsearch.

[Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) is a solution for extracting the data out of the files. Write a file system crawler using Tika. Then use the  Rest API to index the data.

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, have a look on the [FSCrawler](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/fscrawler-2.5/index.html) project. [Here](https://medium.com/cloudnesil/indexing-file-system-and-file-contents-with-elasticsearh-c66c5c0b675f) is a blogpost describing how to solve a task you are facing.

Good luck!